# Box positioning wrapper

Tags: html, css

I'm brand new to this. I'm trying to create my first webpage. I want three boxes placed inside my wrapper - it should look like this drawing: https://ibb.co/xGDCv2f

I basically want to place three boxes inside the wrapper. "Registrer Pant", "Nexus Fordele" and "Samlet Donation" I'm kinda clueless how to, though.

MY HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Registrer Pant</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Forside.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <h1>Godmorgen, Mathias</h1>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">

</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="box1" class="Pant">
    Registrer Pant
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="box2" class="Nexus">
    Nexus fordele
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="box3" class="Samlet">
    Samlet donation
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

MY CSS:

```
.header {
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #4968aa;
    color: white;
}

.header h1 {
    font-size: 40px;

}

#wrapper {
    width: 1260px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid black;

}

.Pant {
    background-color: #BCBCBA;
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 100px;

#box2 {
    background-color: lime;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100px;

}

#box3 {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100px;

}
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: Hey there you really need to get ride of all the `<br/>` code as that wont be helping you. A good place to start is somewhere like here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/ - also you can use a layout tool like bootstarp to help you. A lot of websites use bootstrap frame work as it just makes it quicker to put your site together. So its worth while learning as well - https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the boxes in the wrapper don't close the wrapper div (with `</div>`) until after the boxes' HTML.

Then just some minor adjustments in the CSS.

```css
.header {
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4968aa;
  color: white;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 1260px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.Pant {
  background-color: #BCBCBA;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 300px;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

#box2 {
  background-color: lime;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#box3 {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Godmorgen, Mathias</h1>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="box1" class="Pant">
    Registrer Pant
  </div>
  <div id="box2" class="Nexus">
    Nexus fordele
  </div>

  <div id="box3" class="Samlet">
    Samlet donation
  </div>
</div>
```